# Kafka custom state store is not getting updated

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to build a custom state store which stores key to map of values.

***Stream & Store configuration***

```
        final Serde<HashMap<String, ?>> userSessionsSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(new HashMapSerializer(), new HashMapDeserializer());
        StoreBuilder sessionStoreBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(storeName), 
                        Serdes.String(), 
                        userSessionsSerde);
        builder.addStateStore(sessionStoreBuilder);
        
        builder.stream("connection-events", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), wsSerde))
            .transform(wsEventTransformerSupplier, storeName)
            .to("status-changes", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
        streams.start();
```

***Transformer***

```
public class WSEventProcessor implements Transformer<String, ConnectionEvent, KeyValue<String, String>> {

    private String storeName = "user-sessions";
    private KeyValueStore<String, Map<String, ConnectionEvent>> stateStore;

    final Serde<HashMap<String, ?>> userSessionsSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(new HashMapSerializer(), new HashMapDeserializer());

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        stateStore = (KeyValueStore<String, Map<String, ConnectionEvent>>) context.getStateStore(storeName);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, ConnectionEvent value) {
        boolean sendUpdate = false;
    
        //Send null if there are no updates to be sent to downstream processors
        if(value.getState() == WebSocketConnection.CONNECTED) {
            if(stateStore.get(key) == null) {
                stateStore.put(key, new HashMap<>());
                sendUpdate = true;
            }
            stateStore.get(key).put(value.getSessionId(), value);
            return sendUpdate ? KeyValue.pair(key, "Online") : null;
        }
        else {
            stateStore.get(key).remove(value.getSessionId());
            int size = stateStore.get(key).size();
            return stateStore.get(key).isEmpty() ? KeyValue.pair(key, "Offline") : null;
        }
    }

}
```

The state store always has 0 size map for each key irrespective of connected and disconnected events. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

value object that you stored into `stateStore.put(key, value)` and `stateStore.get(key)` are different objects (as it serialized and then deserialized).

Your issue is related to modification of object returned from state store:
`stateStore.get(key).put(value.getSessionId(), value)` and `stateStore.get(key).remove(value.getSessionId())`. when you update object `stateStore.get(key)`, it's actually not persisted to state store, only changes that object.

So, to fix your issue, calculate required value (in your case `HashMap`), and only after that apply `stateStore.put(key, calculated_value)`. If you need to remove key-value from state store, use `stateStore.put(key, null)`. Your `transform` method should look approximately like:

```
public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, ConnectionEvent value) {
    Map<String, Object> valueFromStateStore = stateStore.get(key);
    Map<String, Object> valueToUpdate = ofNullable(valueFromStateStore).orElseGet(Collections::emptyMap);
    KeyValue<String, String> resultKeyValue = null;

    //Send null if there are no updates to be sent to downstream processors
    if(value.getState() == WebSocketConnection.CONNECTED) {
        if(valueToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            resultKeyValue = KeyValue.pair(key, "Online");
        }
        valueToUpdate.put(value.getSessionId(), value);
    }
    else {
        valueToUpdate.remove(value.getSessionId());
        if (valueToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            resultKeyValue = KeyValue.pair(key, "Offline");
        }
    }

    stateStore.put(key, valueToUpdate);
    return resultKeyValue;
}
```

Comment: You mean I need to get map from state store and create another local map object, add new value to map and then write it back to state store. We can only write to state store and not update existing value. Is it right?

Comment: yes, partially correct. you need to get map from state store, then update it (either update returned object or creating a new one, it's up to you), and then put map to state store back

Comment: you can update map that was returned from `stateStore.get(key)`, but the issue with your code is that such update not visible for state store

Comment: How can I store the results after transformation to GlobalKTable?